# fullCalendar.js: align events in the same horizontal line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

In a nutshell, this is what I have now:

[image]

*the triangle and the circle are two different event in the same say. Now they are aligned vertically on top of eachother.*

And this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

*The two events are aligned horizontally.*

So `float: left` doesn't work here because the events in full calendar are `absolute`ly positioned to the  main calendar's div. It has to do something with moving dynamically the `top` and `left` by detecting which events are on the bottom lines. But how?

Comment: Do you have some code??

Answer (score 1):

If the events are positioned against the main calendar div, what you'll need to do is use $("#day").position to get the x/y position of the day you want, then set the top and left of the event divs to that x/y, with the second event having position x+(width)/y

So something like

```
var pos = $("#day").position;
$("#event1").css({"top": pos.top, "left":pos.left});
$("#event2").css({"top": pos.top, "left":pos.left+25});
```

Comment: quick way to get the specific day position?

Comment: That's implementation specific. I'd do it by assigning each day div in your calendar a unique ID (6 rows of 7 days for 42 unique cells), and then just looking it up with day number + month offset.  So if you want to look up thursday, july 11 2013, you'd see that this month's offset is 1 so you attach your events to the 12th div

Comment: argh god it would be so much easier if you could assign the events to `.fc-day-content`

Comment: Based on my understanding of the fullcalendar plugin, every day has a .fc-day-content div in it, so that wouldn't help. But I was also under the impression event data was appended into .fc-day-content, and not positioned absolutely to the full calendar.

Comment: yup, and every day has also `data-date` attribute, so it is unique.

Comment: What is the parent of the event div? Is it the full calendar, or the day the event data is appended to? If it's the latter things get easier

Comment: it's fullCalendar. That's why it's a pain in the ass.

Comment: Okay, I solved it by detecting which events has the same time value has the days, then I appended a new div to the .fc-day. Argh, long day.